# Parcelable class with exception as attribute (Android)

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I want to send an object from an activity to another using Parcelable in the class. I have a Parcelable class that has two strings and an Exception as attributes.

```
public class ReportErrorVO implements Parcelable {

    private String titleError;
    private String descriptionError;
    private Exception exceptionError;

    public ReporteErrorVO(Parcel in) {
        titleError = in.readString();
        descriptionError = in.readString();
        exceptionError = ????; //What do I put here?
    }

    public ReporteErrorVO() {
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {    
        dest.writeString(titleError);
        dest.writeString(descriptionError);
        dest.writeException(exceptionError);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public ReportErrorVO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ReportErrorVO(in);
        }

        public ReportErrorVO[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ReportErrorVO[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    //Getter and setters atributes...
}
```

What can I do to set the exception in the parcelable attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, doing it this way helped me to get things working: Send the exception on an array.

```
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {    
        dest.writeString(mTitleError);
        dest.writeString(mDescriptionError);
        Exception[] exceptions = new Exception[1];
        exceptions[0] = mExceptionError;
        dest.writeArray(exceptions);
    }

public ReportErrorVO(Parcel in) {
        mTitleError = in.readString();
        mDescriptionError = in.readString();
        Object[] exceptions = in.readArray(Exception.class.getClassLoader());
        mExceptionError = (Exception) exceptions[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use readException method `in.readException()` and this method will throw the exception if it had been written to the parcel, so you may catch it and save to your variable.

```
    try {
        in.readException();
    } catch (Exception e){
        exceptionError = e;
    }
```

Note that this method only supports limited types of exceptions

```
The supported exception types are:
     * BadParcelableException
     * IllegalArgumentException
     * IllegalStateException
     * NullPointerException
     * SecurityException
     * NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: and what do I have to put in the writeToParcel method to write the exception? Because the way I am using it, I am getting IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity (I may think that the exception is being excecuted)